# Is it possible to use ssh git repo url with helm?

Tags: git, ssh, kubernetes-helm

Using `helm pull` with an `ssh://` url fails right away:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ helm pull --destination /tmp/xyz --version 0.0.1 --repo ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/MyOrg/MyProject/MyRepo MyChart
Error: could not find protocol handler for: ssh
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

My local git works with `ssh://` just fine:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp$ git clone ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/MyOrg/MyProject/MyRepo xyz
Cloning into 'xyz'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 2672 objects to send. (97 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (2672/2672), 380.31 KiB | 6.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (692/692), done.
mark@L-R910LPKW:/tmp$
```

Is there a way to make `helm` pull from a git repo using SSH key?

**EDIT 1**

My question is about helm specifically. I am not interested in workarounds where I clone the repo myself and then point helm to it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can configure Helm to pull from a Git repository using an SSH key by following these steps:

1- Generate an SSH key pair on your local machine if you haven't already done so. You can do this using the ssh-keygen command.

2- Add the public key to the Git repository that you want to pull from. This step will depend on the Git hosting service you are using. For example, if you're using GitHub, you can go to your repository settings and add the public key to the "Deploy keys" section.

3- Configure Helm to use the SSH key by adding the following lines to your values.yaml file:

```
git:
  sshKey: |
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    # Add your private key here
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Replace the # Add your private key here placeholder with your actual private key. Make sure to use the correct indentation and format.

4- Set the git.url value in your values.yaml file to the SSH URL of your Git repository. For example:

```
git:
  url: git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git
```

5- Use the helm dependency update command to pull the chart dependencies from the Git repository using the SSH key.

With these steps, Helm should be able to pull the chart dependencies from the Git repository using the SSH key.

Here is an example values.yaml file that configures Helm to use an SSH key to pull a chart from a Git repository:

```
git:
  url: git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git
  ref: main
  sshKey: |
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    # Add your private key here
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Where does this `values.yaml` go? Because neither `helm pull` nor `helm dependency update` accept `values.yaml` on the command line. Do you mean I need to commit it into the git repo alongside Chart.yaml? If so, I cannot do it for the obvious reasons. Please, clarify. Thank you.

Comment: why so limited, can add more lines in the file???